# How does Spark decide the partitions number of the next stage when shuffle in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Of course I know the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`config,
but for example, when I set this config 300 on the small dataset which just has 200 rows, the config is not valid, the actual partition number is just 2,
anthor example, I set this config 3000 on the dataset which has 30 billion rows, the config is not valid too, the actual partition number is just 600,
we see that when we set a big value partitions config on a small dataset, the config would be not valid,
So I just want to know How does Spark decide the partitions number of the next stage when shuffle in SparkSQL? Or How to force this config to be valid ?
My Spark SQL is just like below:

```
set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=3000;
with base_data as (
select 
    device_id
from
   table_name
where
    dt = '20210621'
distribute by
    rand()
)
select count(1) from base_data
```

Comment: If you decide not to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, Spark uses the default = 200. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: @mazaneicha I have updated my answer, please see again, thanks

Comment: Could you please add an output of `explain` to your question too?

Answer (score 0):

In general Narrow transformation does not change number of partitions .

Wide transformations transformation does not change number of partitions.

**Narrow transformation** In Narrow transformation, all the elements that are required to compute the records in single partition live in the single partition of parent RDD. A limited subset of partition is used to calculate the result. Narrow transformations are the result of map(), filter().

**Wide transformation** — In wide transformation, all the elements that are required to compute the records in the single partition may live in many partitions of parent RDD. The partition may live in many partitions of parent RDD. Wide transformations are the result of groupbyKey and reducebyKey.

**Update after question change:**

you can assume "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" as a query hint where we are forcing executors that make that number of partitions for joins or aggregations in my view we should not play with this value unless we are very sure that what are no of grouping key would be.

This will make unnecessary shuffling of data over the network.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see again, thanks

Comment: @Shawn.X I have added an update hope this will help you to understant.